# Solr indexing multi value fields

Tags: solr, indexing, lucene, faceted-search

I'm starting to learn solr and I'm trying to model the data for prices of products in different bundles.

e.g.

```
Product {
allPrices: { 12, 13, 14 }
bundles:   {Bundle_1, Bundle_2, Bundle_3}
price:     ????
}
```

I left the `price` field because this is how initialy the faceted search worked. There was just one price value that was indexed and it was used for filtering.

I have a products page where I have a dropdown of bundles I can select. Depending on the bundle I select the corresponding price needs to be shown.
How cand I model this behavior to make it possible to have a faceted search and to use SOLR `ranges`.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to take a look at Block Join approach in Solr. It will work very well for your needs. You could model you product as a parent document, and all 3 bundles as a child products. Each will have it's own price, so you could show it easily. The problem here is, that Solr still don't have child level facet, so you will need to implement it on your own. Also, Solr couldn't sort docs by children fields, so you will need to make an aggregation

I recommend this article as a start for you - http://blog.griddynamics.com/2013/09/solr-block-join-support.html

Another approach could be to model each bundle as a single document. You could have 3 docs here.

```
Bundle1 {
   price: 12,
   name: Bundle_1
   product: Product1
}
Bundle2 {
   price: 13,
   name: Bundle_2
   product: Product1
}
```

However, this approach will have some problems as well - your data will grow exponentially, since you will create doc for every bundle you have.